# Copy selection but lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this handy script to copy and paste the value of an input:

```
$(document).on('click','div.copy',function(){
 $('>input',this).select()
 document.execCommand('copy')
})
```

My font is uppercase for style purposes. I would like to select and copy a lowercase version of the value.

I've tried:

```
$(document).on('click','div.copy',function(){
 $('>input',this).val().toLowerCase().select()
 document.execCommand('copy')
})
```

But I am getting an error saying that it is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Generally, accessing the user's clipboard from the browser is not very straightforward for security reasons. I've created a workardound snippet. You set the value of the control to the lowercase value, select it, then copy.

Alternatively you could look into the [Clipboard api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

```js
$(document).on('click','div.copy',function(){
 var control = $('>input',this);
 var txt = control.val();
 control.val(txt.toLowerCase());
 control.select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
 control.val(txt);
 control.select();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copy"><input type="text" value="FOO"/></div>
```

Comment: That, however, mutates the value of the input. I guess that shouldn't be the case?

Comment: Yes, that's the price to pay for a simple workaround. Other venues include off-screen hidden textareas etc, but then you have to fake focus, like code-editors often do. Or you can use content-editable divs, like WYSIWYG editors often do. All possible, all not really trivial.

I suppose we could change the value back to the original after copy. Let me see if I can update the snippet.

@Terry updated to revert back to original value after copy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Slavormir for the answer.

I also found another easy solution using CSS. I forgot to mention that my uppercase is controlled by CSS `text-transform:uppercase` so the above solution will not work for CSS transformed text.

If you have `text-transform:uppercase`, you could do:

```
$(document).on('click','div.copy',function(){
 $('>input',this).css('text-transform','lowercase').select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
 $('>input',this).css('text-transform','');
});
```